# I can't make the timer to run second time properly, What is wrong and how can i fix it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created a new class and added a timer.
I'm calling the StartTimer and StopTimer in 4 places in MainActivity.java.
The first two places i'm calling it two buttons that start and stop it's working fine. The second place i'm calling it again in two cases to start and stop it's not working fine i see the numbers in the timer not running like it's trying to but it's stuck on the 0.

This is the class with the timer:

```
package com.test.webservertest;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by me on 11/18/2015.
 */

public class Timers
{
    private long startTime = 0L;
    private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
    private long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    private long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    private long updatedTime = 0L;
    private String recordtimer;
    private Runnable updateTimerThread;

    public void StartTimer(TextView timerValue, String text) {
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread = new UpdateTimerThread(timerValue, text), 0);
    }

    public void StopTimer(TextView timerValue) {
        timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
        customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
    }


    public class UpdateTimerThread implements Runnable {
        protected TextView timerValue;
        protected String textToAdd;

        public UpdateTimerThread(TextView timerValue, String text) {
            this.timerValue= timerValue;
            this.textToAdd = text;
        }

        public void run() {

            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (timeInMilliseconds / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int hours = mins / 60;
            mins = mins % 60;
            recordtimer = textToAdd + String.format("%02d", hours) + ":" + String.format("%02d", mins) + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs);
            timerValue.post(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    timerValue.setText(recordtimer);
                }
            });
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is where i'm using it where it's not working fine:

```
Thread serverChecksThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Looper.prepare();
        Looper l = Looper.myLooper();
        customHandler = new Handler(l);
        customHandler.postDelayed(serverChecksRunnable, 0);
        Looper.loop();
    }
});

    Runnable serverChecksRunnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if (startuploadstatusthread == true)
            {
                checkServer = Get(iptouse + "uploadstatus");

            }

            Handler h=new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            h.post(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if (startuploadstatusthread == true)
                    {
                        if (checkServer != null)
                        {
                            String a = null;
                            try
                            {
                                a = new String(checkServer, "UTF-8");
                                textforthespeacch = a;
                                if (textforthespeacch.contains("upload completed"))
                                {
                                    String[] parts = textforthespeacch.split(",");
                                    String varr = parts[0];
                                    String varr1 = parts[1];
                                    String varr2 = parts[2];
                                    textforthespeacch = varr;
                                    status1.setText("Upload completed" + " " + varr1 + "%");
                                    timers.StopTimer(timerValueUpload);
                                    numberofuploadedfilescounter += 1;
                                    uploadedfilescount.setText(("Uploaded Files: " + numberofuploadedfilescounter));
                                    startuploadstatusthread = false;
                                    MainActivity.this.initTTS();
                                }
                                if (textforthespeacch.contains("uploading"))
                                {
                                    timers.StartTimer(timerValueUpload, "Uploading Time: ");
                                    String[] split = textforthespeacch.split(" ");
                                    textforthespeacch = split[0];
                                    status1.setText("Uploading" + " " + split[1] + "%");
                                    servercheckCounter += 1;
                                    if (servercheckCounter == 1)
                                    {
                                        MainActivity.this.initTTS();
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

            customHandler.postDelayed(serverChecksRunnable,1000);
        }
    };
```

In the top of the MainActivity:

```
private TextView timerValueUpload;
```

Then in onCreate:

```
serverChecksThread.start();
timerValueUpload = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValueUpload);
```

The way i'm calling in the Thread serverChecksThread the timerstop and timerstart is like this:

```
timers.StopTimer(timerValueUpload);
timers.StartTimer(timerValueUpload, "Uploading Time: ");
```

First i'm clicking the buttons of the Record where it's working start and stop the timer. Then it's getting to this Thread but instead starting the timer over again and then stop it it's making this problem i see that it's stuck on 0 and i see the 0 of the second blinking.

Maybe something wrong calling the StopTimer and StartTimer inside this Thread ?

Comment: I found the problem i guess. I'm running the Runnable serverChecksRunnable every second over and over again. And what it does is starting the timer over and over again it's starting the timer timers.StartTimer every second that's what i see the 0 of the seconds blinking since it's starting over again every second. Only in the end when it's getting to the timers.StopTimer then i see the timer start working and counting the seconds but it should stop.

Comment: Somehow i need to make that it will start the timer only once and then stop it only once. How can i do it ?